# Why should I use javascript call method?

Tags: javascript, apply, call

I'm trying to understand the **call** and **apply** methods in javascript. But I didn't understand why I should use it.

```
var person = {
   fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
 }
}

var person1 = {
 firstName:"John",
 lastName: "Doe"
}
var person2 = {
 firstName:"Mary",
 lastName: "Doe"
}
var x = person.fullName.call(person1);
```

I can do this example without using call and apply.

```
var person = {
   fullName: function(firstName, lastName) {
     return firstName + " " + lastName;
 }
}
var person1 = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName: "Doe"
}
var person2 = {
  firstName:"Mary",
  lastName: "Doe"
}
var x = person.fullName(person1.firstName, person1.lastName);
```

Or I don't understand this example.

```
function Product(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Pizza(name) {
   Product.call(this,name);
}

const pizza = new Pizza("Margherita");
```

When I think of this example, I can do with the prototype. Why use call or apply? Thank you

Comment: @Rup is correct

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Can you check it now?

Comment: Okay, I totally changed the sample. What I want to know is where should I actually use it? @Rup

Comment: You use `.call` so the `this` context of a method is called in another context outside of its original context. By the way, using prototype in the last example would also be a waste if you just want a `new Product`.

Answer (score 1):

A good use case is when you want to 'borrow' a function with a different context. Take the example below, you can definitely use inheritance to give Cat the `bark` function but maybe you don't want that function to exist on every instance but only want to use it in certain situations.

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name
    this.bark = function() {
        console.log('woof' + this.name)
    }
}
const dog = new Dog('spot')

dog.bark() // woofspot


function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name
}
const cat = new Cat('cat')

dog.bark.call(cat) // woofcat
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is all a matter of preference on which you use, but you must use call and/or apply, you cannot do it without them.

Comment: I don't understand why I can't. But if you say it's a matter of choice, I get it.

Comment: If you remove both, you should get what @Rup posted under comments.

Comment: Look at this article https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp

Comment: Okay, I totally changed the sample. What I want to know is where should I actually use it? @Death Waltz

Comment: @omerstack look at the other answer, It does a better job of explaining than I did

Answer (score 0):

```
function Product(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

function Pizza(name) {
   Product.call(this,name);
}

const pizza = new Pizza("Margherita");
```

That's [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance). Pizza is a product. In other languages, for example PHP, inheritance looks like this:

```
class Foo {

  public function __construct() {
    // Do stuff specific for Foo
  }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

  public function __construct()(
    parent::__construct();
    // Do stuff specific for Bar
  }

}
```

Here, we don't have `extends` and in order to make it work, you need to say that the `this` in the parent constructor is the child.

Using `call`, you can say what the `this` in the `Product()` function/constructor is.
In this case, it is the Pizza object (the new created an object {}). Without using `call`, `Pizza` wouldn't even have a name.

The same goes for your first example

```
var person = {
   fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
 }
}

var person1 = {
 firstName:"John",
 lastName: "Doe"
}
var person2 = {
 firstName:"Mary",
 lastName: "Doe"
}
var x = person.fullName.call(person1);
```

Yes, it worked without calling `call` but not without drastic changes.

`person.fullName.call(person1);` is like saying take this function and permute `this` with  my person1 object. So in the end, it is as though you did this:

```
return person1.firstName + " " + person1.lastName;
```

As to [which one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to use

> Note: While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of call(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts **an argument list**, while apply() accepts **a single array of arguments**.

Comment: Can't I do the same with inheritance? @jperl

Comment: @omerstack what do you mean? that's already inheritance. Pizza inherits from Product. In Pizza, we say call Product but use the context of Pizza (this). So this.name is like saying (Pizza).name = name; and then you can add properties to Pizza after the call to Product.

Comment: I mean, could I do it using Object.create and prototype? Because as I read, we use prototype for inheritance.

Comment: @omerstack please, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance. It also explains how to inherit the methods on the Product's prototype.

Comment: @omerstack the prototype is used for functions shared by instances of an object. But you need to do `call` to inherit the properties in the constructor.

Comment: @jperl Okay, I know we can do this. That's exactly my question. When should I choose which one? Is that a matter of choice?

Comment: the prototype is used for functions shared by instances of an object. But you need to do call to inherit the properties in the constructor.

All right, I'il try and figure this out right away. Thank you. This was descriptive 
@jperl thank you.

Comment: @jperl I should use prototype when inheriting methods. I should use call when inheriting fields.   Do I get it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201038/discussion-between-jperl-and-omerstack).

Comment: @omerstack Sorry for the confusion. My sentence was misleading. The prototype is for all the things (default values, functions or whatever) shared by all instances. So you want to inherit that. But you also want to make sure that you call the constructor of the object you want to inherit from with call (the this will be your object that inherits). I am bad at explaining things. Sorry.